# Keras Progress Bar Output Inconsistent

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have created an CNN using a pertained model with the use of Keras (TensorFlow version: 2.3.1). Every step within the processing chain worked well, and the performance were good. At a later point I needed to switch to an earlier version (TensorFlow version 1.15.3).
Now (with TF version 1.15.3 or any other 1.15.x) I face the problem that each epoch runs twice. Basically each epoch runs completely through all batches and starts again but only runs until batch 62 and ends afterwards. The output of the training (`model.fit()`) is as follows:

[Here you can find the output, as an image (sorry need 10 reputation for inline)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFNRC.png)

The output using textual form:

```
Epoch 1/3
295/295 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5937 - acc: 0.8168Epoch 1/3
296/295 [==============================] - 38s 129ms/step - loss: 0.5939 - acc: 0.8168 - val_loss: 4.3002 - val_acc: 0.1111
Epoch 2/3
295/295 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5350 - acc: 0.8283Epoch 1/3
296/295 [==============================] - 38s 129ms/step - loss: 0.5352 - acc: 0.8283 - val_loss: 4.9280 - val_acc: 0.1111
Epoch 3/3
295/295 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4883 - acc: 0.8417Epoch 1/3
296/295 [==============================] - 38s 129ms/step - loss: 0.4884 - acc: 0.8418 - val_loss: 5.3884 - val_acc: 0.1111
```

I have also found another stack overflow post with the same strange behavior ([keras epoch runs twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61546520/keras-epoch-runs-twice)).  But it did not solve my problem.
I run TensorFlow / Keras using a Docker Container. The following version has been used, where the problem occurs:

`tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.3-gpu-py3-jupyter`

Here is my code:

```
datagen_train = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

generator_train = datagen_train.flow_from_directory(
    cfg.datasource + "/train",
    batch_size=cfg_model.batch_size,
    target_size=cfg_model.img_dest_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
)

datagen_val = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

generator_valid = datagen_val.flow_from_directory(
    cfg.datasource + "/val_0",
    batch_size=cfg_model.batch_size,
    target_size=cfg_model.img_dest_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
)

history = model.fit(
    generator_train,
    epochs=3,
    validation_steps=generator_valid.samples / generator_valid.batch_size,
    steps_per_epoch=generator_train.samples / generator_train.batch_size,
    validation_data=generator_valid,
)
```

The data is split into a training set and a validation set. Each of the subsets are separated in different directories.

When I remove the `validation_data=generator_valid` everything works as usual. So, as it has been mentioned in the other stack overflow post, I think that the validation happens twice. But I don’t know how to fix this.

Current batch size: 8

Graphics Card: Nvidia RTX 2080 Ti

Number of images in training set: 18900 images (within 10 classes)

Number of images in validation set: 4050 images (within 10 classes)

**Update:**

The problem of the inconsistent output of the progress bar occurs at all docker images using the images `tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.X-gpu-py3-jupyter`. This might be a bug in the counter of the progress bar and is still present when switching to another progress bar.

As an workaround I have switched to an older TensorFlow version `tensorflow/tensorflow:1.14.0-gpu-py3-jupyter`.

Comment: What `batch_size` are you using?

Comment: At the beginning (TensorFlow version 2.3.1) I have used a batch size of 64. With the downgrade to the older TF version  I reduced the batch size to 16. After a while I lowered again to 8. My current graphics card is an RTX 2080 Ti.

Comment: And how many samples do you have for generator_valid and generator_train?

Comment: Currently the training set contains 18900 images (within 10 classes) and the validation set contains 4050 images (within 10 classes).